# Get BBOX values from a WMS GetCapabilities response with OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

I am using the below code to get the BBOX values:

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities();
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
url:"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities&",
 success: function(e){
  var response = wms.read(e.responseText);
  var capability = response.capability;
  for (var i=0, len=capability.layers.length; i<len; i+=1) { 
  var layerObj = capability.layers[i]; 
  if (layerObj.name === 'cite:'+layers) { 
  var bounds=OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray(layerObj.bbox).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857") ); 
    mapPanel.map.zoomToExtent(bounds); 
    break; 
  } 
  }
  }
});
```

But I am not getting the exact values, when I debug the code in Firefox it look like this:

[image]

I want the BBOX values shown in the above image. Please tell me the code to get that BBOX values.

Comment: In the GetCapabilities response what is the actual `<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3857" minx="..." miny="..." maxx="..." maxy="..."/>` values reported for your cite layer?

Comment: is the difference before or after you transform the bbox?

Comment: after transform iam getting the different values but i want the values shown in the image. Those values(shown in image) and <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3857" minx="..." miny="..." maxx="..." maxy="..."/> values are same.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it:

```
var bbox = layerObj.bbox["EPSG:3857"].bbox;
```